# Error, Whats missing in Spring NamedJdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-data

I have configured my code to use the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate,

**spring.xml**

```
<bean id="netezzaDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> 
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.netezza.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:netezza://server/DB" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
 </bean> 

<bean id="netezzaJDBCTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="netezzaDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

**DAO**

```
@Component
public class EventDAO 
{
    @Autowired
    private DataSource netezzaDataSource;
    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate netezzaNamedTemplate;

    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate getNetezzaNamedTemplate() 
    {
        return netezzaNamedTemplate;
    }

    public void setNetezzaNamedTemplate(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate netezzaNamedTemplate) 
    {
        this.netezzaNamedTemplate = netezzaNamedTemplate;
    }
    ..........
}
```

But it fails to autowire and throws an exception. Am I missing something?

**Exception Stack**

```
Feb 25, 2014 10:56:48 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@336bc75c: startup date [Tue Feb 25 10:56:48 EST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Feb 25, 2014 10:56:48 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-local-dev.xml]
    Feb 25, 2014 10:56:49 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
    INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5fc7a9de: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,eventDAO,mySQLDataSource,mySQLJDBCTemplate,netezzaDataSource,netezzaJDBCTemplate,netezzaNamedTemplate,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
    Feb 25, 2014 10:56:49 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
    INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    Feb 25, 2014 10:56:49 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
    INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: org.netezza.Driver
    Feb 25, 2014 10:56:49 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory destroySingletons
    INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5fc7a9de: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,eventDAO,mySQLDataSource,mySQLJDBCTemplate,netezzaDataSource,netezzaJDBCTemplate,netezzaNamedTemplate,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate com.omnitracs.fra.dao.EventDAO.netezzaNamedTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'netezzaNamedTemplate' defined in class path resource [spring-local-dev.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.<init>()
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.omnitracs.fra.main.CriticalEventMain.main(CriticalEventMain.java:21)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate com.omnitracs.fra.dao.EventDAO.netezzaNamedTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'netezzaNamedTemplate' defined in class path resource [spring-local-dev.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.<init>()
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 13 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'netezzaNamedTemplate' defined in class path resource [spring-local-dev.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.<init>()
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1007)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.<init>()
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:83)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1000)
        ... 26 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: Let's see your bean declaration for `netezzaNamedTemplate`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use Constructor Injection instead of.

```
<bean id="netezzaJDBCTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="netezzaDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

As NamedParameterJdbcTemplate does not have no args constructor use and because you are using

```
 @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate netezzaNamedTemplate;
```

Configuration need to be like this.

```
   <bean id="netezzaNamedTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
      <constructor-arg ref="netezzaDataSource"/>
   </bean>
```